# Creating multiple Connection objects for multiple users

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, authentication

I have written a web app using Java EE for altering the contents of a table. For user authentication I am using the database credentials of the user. I am creating the JDBC connection using these credentials.

The problem arose when two or more user simultaneously logged in and the Connection object got updated with the credentials of the latest user. So no matter which user made the changes, the username of the latest user gt logged in the log file, which is a massive security issue.

So how can I create multiple Connection objects for multiple users so that the only username of the user who is making the modification gets in the log.

Comment: Curious to know how you get the user information from the connection object.

Comment: For now, it's Netezza, but soon it'll be migrated to Vertica.

Comment: And I am not getting the user information from the connection object, just retaining the username in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds as if you were storing a reference to your connection objects in a static variable, keeping just a single connection object in your web application. Instead of that, you can make use of [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) to store a user-specific connection object in user's session as an [attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29). Store the connection there at the first time user accesses the application, then, at each subsequent request, get the connection [back](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29), check if it is still valid and use it.

Also do not forget to close the connection once the session timeouts. This can be achieved by implementing a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) that checks for any connections in session and closing it in `sessionDestroyed()` method.

**EDIT:** For multiple reasons, it is usually not a good design to use DB credentials to let users log on to an application. However, with low number of sessions (and thus low number of connections simultaneously opened on the DB) and with DB rights reasonably set, this still might work well.

**EDIT 2:** And of course, access to such a cached connection needs to be synchronized (say, in case a user tries to hit your app with multiple simultaneous requests, e.g. by having multiple browser windows open). This might be a (little) tricky.

Comment: Thanks david-a. I'll attempt this and then get back to you. I was previously thinking of creating a HttpSession, but at that point of time, it felt like an unnecessary hassle. But looks like now I'll have to do it anyways.

Comment: Thank you @david a. I added in the session the Connection objects of the individual users and it worked like a charm! :)

Comment: Good - just note the important thing there is to make sure the connections are closed latest at session timeout (using a session listener) and to synchronize access to them.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to store username/password/etc in [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) rather than keeping list of connections opened and assigned to a user. Imagine that there will be tens or hundreds of users - will RDBMS handle such number of concurrent connections correctly? what about thousands of users?

Comment: This is easier to implement, for sure. However, the need to create a connection at each request might add significant latency to the application (depending on database). If I had to implement this (say, DB-users were a requirement), I'd definitely cache the connections, or try to build something like per-user connection pool. Of course, this won't ever scale with growing number of users.

Comment: why  not to authenticate users using the connection, and later on take a connection from a pool? I suppose that some sort of privileges separation on database layer exists, and that is what topicstater actually wants to use.

Comment: The web site won't encounter thousands of simultaneous connections. The maximum I am expecting is 10, and so creating a different set of authentication credentials and validation system didn't seem the right choice to me.

Comment: And as @jdevelop stated, I do want to use the privileges grated to different users on the tables to decide whether they can only view the data or modify it too.

Comment: JDevelop - connection pool would be for sure the best to do, but what would be the credentials that connections in that pool would use?  AFAIK there is no (standard) way to re-authenticate an existing JDBC connection.